Will activating Parameter Manager overwrite any utms that have been manually applied to links?
We currently do not use Parameter Manager in Marketing Cloud. Instead, all URLs are manually created with the correct UTMs (source, medium, campaign, and content) and added separately to emails. With this setup, we have a number of automated campaigns and journeys running.
I want to move to a more automated approach and implement UTM in the parameter manager. What will happen to the links within live campaigns if I do this? Will it overwrite them with new UTMs or add additional ones (potentially leading to a campaign with 2 UTM_mediums, etc.)? What steps should I take to ensure a smooth changeover?

When you switch to using Parameter Manager, the system will automatically append UTM parameters to the links in your emails. If your existing links already contain UTM parameters, this can potentially lead to conflicts. Specifically, you might end up with duplicate parameters (e.g., two utm_medium values), which can cause tracking issues. I would suggest you work with Salesforce support to get more impact analysis.
The first line it says it appends them to the messages
